# Jaspersoft subreport with source code

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have my reports stored into a database as the source code. I need to then use this source code in my report as a subreport.

When I give the subreport expression the source code, it thinks it is a path to the file.

Is there a way to do this without needing to store the source code as a .japser file?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRSubreport.html) `subreportExpression` can return a JasperReport object too.

Comment: currently it is a comes in as a string, how do i convert it into a JasperReport object?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->

<!-- 2017-05-31T10:33:33 -->

<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
   
      SOME CODE HERE

</jasperReport>`

Comment: Is the main report sourced from database?